# How do I use feynmf or mf with miktex?

Tags: miktex, feynmf

I am trying to use feynmf with miktex on my windows machine to make Feynman diagrams.  When I follow the instructions in the template file that comes with feynmf, it does not produce the dvi file correctly.

I am compiling it by running:

```
latex template
mf fmftempl
latex template
```

Since the log file is long I have posted the mf log on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/4Gbw792W

It seems like the instructions for compiling it are not correct since this seems pretty simple.  I've also had this problem on more than one windows machine so I don't think it's a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

(This maybe should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep.)

I get the same error using MacTeX 2010, even with an even more minimal example. There seems to be a problem with `feynmf`. If you change `\usepackage{feynmf}` to `\usepackage{feynmp}` in `template.tex` and then run

```
latex template
mpost fmftempl
latex template
```

it works fine for me.